# PHP 7.1.3 Foreach on child class built with static properties prints unexpected output

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, static

I am working with PHP 7.1.3 locally on Windows with EasyPHP.

**This is just a test code**, I am pretty sure I am missing something here but I would like a little help to understand the problem.

In this case, a short explanation:

I have

- a Form Class to create Forms
- an Abstract InputField Class, used to create generic Input Fields for a form, with common properties and methods for every field
- an InputFieldText Class extending InputField, which has to create only input text fields.

Form has a method addField(array $attributes) and a property $fields=[].

When I add a field to the Form, I set up the field attributes (in this test, just the name of the field), then I cycle form fields with a Foreach to output each field.

If I do this with public properties it seems to work fine, I put this here only to show that the code is working, as I said this is just a test so please don't judge code quality or standards:

```php
<?php
// THIS WORKS
class Form
{
    public $fields=[];

    public function addField($attributes)
    {
        $field=new InputFieldText();
        $field->setAttributes($attributes);
        $this->fields[]=clone $field;
        unset($field);
    }
}

abstract class InputField
{
    public $name='';

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setAttributes(array $attributes)
    {
        $this->name=$attributes['name'];
    }
}

class InputFieldText extends InputField
{
}

$form=new Form();
$form->addField(['name'=>'Test1']);
$form->addField(['name'=>'Test2']);
foreach ($form->fields as $k=>$field) {
    echo $field->getName();
}
// OUTPUT OK: Test1Test2
?>
```

Meanwhile if I try with static properties, which I thought was better, I get an output I can't understand:

```php
<?php
// NOT WORKING as I expected
class Form
{
    public $fields=[];

    public function addField($attributes)
    {
        $field=new InputFieldText();
        $field->setAttributes($attributes);
        $this->fields[]=clone $field;
        unset($field);
    }
}

abstract class InputField
{
    public static $name='';

    public function getName()
    {
        return static::$name;
    }

    public function setAttributes(array $attributes)
    {
        static::$name=$attributes['name'];
    }
}

class InputFieldText extends InputField
{    
}

$form=new Form();
$form->addField(['name'=>'Test1']);
$form->addField(['name'=>'Test2']);
foreach ($form->fields as $k=>$field) {
    echo $field->getName();
}
// OUTPUT: Test2Test2
?>
```

I don't understand why, in the second portion of code, the output is Test2Test2 instead of Test1Test2 like in the 1st portion of code. What am I missing?

For some reasons, it seems that using static properties the foreach always refers to the last object, which seems to override the previous objects.

Is this because **static::$name=$attributes['name']** is always referring to the last created Object? But even so, I am creating a new InputFieldText every time I do addField() and then I clone and unset the object, so why does the first object get overriden by the second object?

Comment: In your `InputField` abstract class, you have a `static` name - this means it is shared amongst all instances of any particular class - so all `InputFieldText` objects share the same name.

Comment: I see, this is probably what I was missing, that Static properties will change the value of the property for all instances... I am reading more about this, thanks.
In other cases, I used to use static on child classes because it seemed to work better, but I guess it works better only if you are creating only one instance of each class at each time.

Comment: I am getting output with static.
Also you cantry "self" instead on static